# Fuzzy screenshot comparison with Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, comparison, levenshtein-distance

I'm using Selenium to automate webpage functional testing.  It's important for us to do a pixel-by-pixel comparison when we roll out new code, so we're using Selenium to take screenshots and comparing the base64 encoded strings to see if anything has changed.

We're finding that in practice, it's hard to get complete pixel consistency, especially with images.  I would like minor blurriness / rendering artifacts to count as a "pass" instead of a "fail", so I'm wondering if there's a way of doing a fuzzy comparison to make our tests a bit less fragile.

I was thinking of maybe looking at the Levenshtein distance between the base64 strings as a starting point, but I don't really know if that's a good approach, or what the tolerances should be that distinguish "something moved on the page" from "rendering artifact".  Any ideas / approaches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I ended up going with the ImageMagick command-line tool (because why re-invent image comparison).  The "Peak Absolute Error" metric of the "compare" tool tells you how much you have to fuzz pixels before two images are identical.  This seems to work well... for an image with slight graphical distortions, there might be a lot of pixels that don't match, but slight fuzzing is enough to make them match; but for two images that are actually different, even though most pixels might match, the ones that don't tend to be very different.  Right now I'm checking for a PAE of less than 15% to see if the images should be counted as identical.  Command line I'm using is:

```
 compare -metric PAE  original.png new.png comparison.png
```

Documentation on ImageMagick's compare tool is here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [perceptualdiff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/) which uses a model of the human visual system to try to avoid reporting unnoticeable changes (the authors used for renderer regression testing). Usage is quite simple:

```
perceptualdiff -output diff.ppm baseline.png test.png
```

(where `diff.ppm` is a [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) format image highlighting the areas of difference)

The [needle](http://needle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) regression testing framework has support for using pdiff to compare screenshots:

http://needle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#engines

Comment: That sounds really cool!  So far ImageMagick's been working for me, so I'm probably gonna stick with the if-it-ain't-broke principle, but if I were doing it from scratch I would definitely check perceptualdiff out.

Comment: Strong agreement on not changing something which is working – every project's needs are slightly different. I'm actually looking at updating needle to allow general external diff support so I can use ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use an image format that does not create artifacts (like BMP or [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)) then you can do a per-pixel comparison.
I think you can check each pixel with a common [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions).
To improve performance a little, do not calculate the square root but check the squares of the distances

```
// Maximum color distance allowed to define pixel consistency.
const float maxDistanceAllowed = 5.0;

// Square of the distance, used in calculations.
float maxD = maxDistanceAllowed * maxDistanceAllowed;

public bool isPixelConsistent(Color pixel1, Color pixel2)
{
    // Euclidean distance in 3-dimensions.
    float distanceSquared = (pixel1.R - pixel2.R)*(pixel1.R - pixel2.R) + (pixel1.G - pixel2.G)*(pixel1.G - pixel2.G) + (pixel1.B - pixel2.B)*(pixel1.B - pixel2.B);

    // If the actual distance is less than the max allowed, the pixel is
    // consistent and the method returns TRUE
    return distanceSquared <= maxD;
}
```

Didn't test the C# code, but it should give you the idea. Give some tries and adjust the `maxDistanceAllowed` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking for something similar there is Depicted-[dpxdt](https://github.com/bslatkin/dpxdt). It is designed to be used as part of a CI/CD process.

It combines perceptual diff with server, commandline tool, wrapper for phantom js.

It has functionality demonstrated like crawling entire site and comparing pages for differences.