# Testing JavaScript charts

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, charts, d3.js

I am currently in a project where I'm building charts using various libraries (d3 and nvd3 most of the time). I would like to build a set of automated tests and see if the data I'm feeding into the API I'm making is actually spitting out the data correctly.

How do you actually test charts? Is unit testing the right way to go for this, or is eyeballing the chart the only way to do this?

Comment: You could compare the generated chart to an "expected" chart (e.g. compare the DOM trees), but this might be quite brittle depending on your requirements.

Comment: Selenium can also be used to automatically compare screenshots; this would be more useful for: "is this outputting the same charts it was a week ago" not "will this charting code correctly display all the kinds of data it could be sent" 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284915/fuzzy-screenshot-comparison-with-selenium

Comment: To some extent, the SVG markup provides an abstraction layer (i.e. it abstracts out the actual rendering). So one option here is to test the generated SVG, rather than screenshots - this should be a bit less brittle, as it wouldn't break with CSS changes or anti-aliasing issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PhantomJS to take some screenshots : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture

You can also compare the generated DOM structure (that's what I did on this project : https://github.com/angular-d3/line-chart)

Answer (score 0):

You can write unit tests specific to charts using tape.js

Also you can check out this **library** written specifically to test out charts: https://github.com/magiq-tests/magiq-tests